# Business Objects (webi) stuck forever on retrieving data for specific dates

Tags: business-objects

In BO webintelligence, I am doing a very simple query, retrieve Sales Amount for dates between 2012 and 2013. Just for this simple query when I run it, my BO crashes or gets stuck on "please wait" window. Why is this happening? If I select like 3 or 4 days like between Jan 1st 2012 and Jan 4th 2012, it runs fine. Is there anything from my end that I am doing wrong? This is in production mode.

I also wanted to point out that I have tried limiting my data set for specific region etc.

Comment: Are you sure the problem is BO and not the query?  Can you run the SQL outside of BO?

Answer (score 0):

Too many unknowns to successfully assist.  I presume this is webi 3.1.x or 4.1.x and I presume that the Sales Amount is a measure and that your query includes a date which does not include a time component.  If you only have these two objects in your results pane and have the region in your conditions then pulling something like [Date] and sum([Sales Amt]) should not take long to execute.  As previous poster suggests, try to execute the sql in a tool like SQL*Developer or Management Studio or however the source database / OLAP is stored.

Even though you've limited the data to a "region" this may be too much data.  Try selecting a smaller result set of 100 rows or changing the option for "retrieve duplicate rows" on the query panel.

If possible, post the query from your report using generic object names?